# Linux does not see a hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, disk-management

There are two hard disks on my machine and Linux can only see one of them, while Windows recognizes both disks.

Ubuntu version 20.04
Hard drive 1: Samsung evo 840 500GB SSD (this one ubuntu recognizes)
Hard drive 2: Toshiba 256GB SSD (this one ubuntu does not recognize)

Now it should be formatted as NTFS because it has had Windows installed previously. Right now Ubuntu cannot see it at all - neither during installation, nor using `lsblk` or `fdisk -a`

P.S. WINDOWS IS NOT ON MY SYSTEM ANYMORE! ONLY LINUX. SO I CANT BOOT TO WINDOWS ANYMORE!

How to fix this issue?

```
lsblk:

sda                                             8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk  
├─sda1                                          8:1    0   300M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                                          8:2    0 448,4G  0 part  
│ └─luks-5a1caa97-b5f0-4f67-bed7-0709530dec22 253:0    0 448,4G  0 crypt /
└─sda3                                          8:3    0    17G  0 part  
  └─luks-d7e6d538-b262-40a7-a916-3707d65bf2ee 253:1    0    17G  0 crypt [SWAP]
```

Comment: Editet my Original post

Comment: windows is not there anymore so I cannot enter it

Comment: Think you will have to try to install Windows again to adjust/fix drive, unless it is hardware caused(loose/bad connection to SSD or dead SSD). Need woeusb or mkusb to make windows USB from Ubuntu.

Comment: What does "fixed" mean to you? That linux can use both drives, or that windows is accessible again? I assume not the latter, since you state it's not installed any more. Can you post the output of lsblk?

Comment: Please use the { } icon to format multi-line pasted output from the terminal.

Comment: Check your BIOS - does it see the second hard drive available in its connected hardware information?  If not, then your TOshiba SSD is dead or misconnected in the system.

Comment: @ThomasWard yes, BIOS does see my Toshiba hard drive

Comment: Is this your new computer? Did both SSD's come installed, or did you install one? Your last comment indicated "Toshiba hard drive", but your question indicates SSD. Please clarify. Did this computer come with Optane memory?

Comment: I bought a used laptop. As far as I understand samsung 500gb ssd comes originally with the laptop and toshiba SSD has been added by the previous owner. Toshiba is SSD, sorry for my earlier mistake. Sorry, what is an Optane memory?